# OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected(using python sockets)

Tags: python, python-sockets

OK, so I have done some research, and apparently this has to do with connections dropping, however it only happens when I try to receive the message. I have no idea what is wrong.

Here is the server:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
header = '64'
host = '192.168.0.48'
port = 5050
addr = host, port
disconnect = 'GVhdmU='

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


server.bind(addr)
server.listen(10)
print(f'[LISTENING] on {addr}')


while True:
    clientsocket, address = server.accept()
    print(f'[TMP CONNECTION] from {address}')
    msg_test = server.recv(64)
    msg_test = msg_test.decode('utf-8')
    if msg_test == header:
        msg_encode = server.recv(1000000000000000000)
        msg = msg_encode.decode('utf-8')
    elif msg == disconnect:
        clientsocket.close()
    else:
        clientsocket.close()
```

Note: Yes, I am aware of the incorrect header.

Here is the client:

```
import socket

host = '192.168.0.48'
port = 5050
addr = host, port

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client.connect(addr)
print('CONNECTED')

while True:
    msg = input('What do you want to say to the server:')
    header = '64'
    client.send(bytes(header, 'utf-8'))
    client.send(bytes(msg, 'utf-8'))
    disconnect = input('Do you want to end(answer yes or no):')
    if disconnect == no:
        print("we're starting again")
    if disconnect == yes:
        client.send(bytes('bGVhdmU=', 'utf-8'))
        break
```

Note: This is across my network from one device to another.

Comment: The numbers you pass to recv don't make much sense. Also, you'll want to use `.sendall()` when sending.

Answer (score 1):

Your server code is reading from the wrong socket.

After `accept()` returns `clientsocket`, it needs to read (and write) using `clientsocket`, not `server`.

So change `server.recv()` to `clientsocket.recv()`.